# Prometheus: Hadoop Monitoring using JMX Exporter

Tags: monitoring, hadoop2, prometheus

I am very new to Prometheus and monitoring and working on getting JMX-Exporter setup for my Windows-based Hadoop installation for small POC.

I tried putting in following line in "hadoop_installation\bin\hdfs.cmd\"

```
set HADOOP_OPTS=%HADOOP_OPTS% "-javaagent:C:\path\to\jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.11.0.jar=1985:C:\path\to\conf\hadoop.yml"
```

following is my hadoop.yml

```
rules:
 - pattern: Hadoop<service=ResourceManager, name=MetricsSystem, sub=Stats><>NumAllSources
   name: sources
   labels:
    app_id: "hadoop_rm"
```

Now when I run start-all.cmd

It gives me errors,

```
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "C"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JavaAgent.premain(JavaAgent.java:42)
        ... 6 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
```

I am not sure whether I am on the right track for this?

Is there any other way except readymade FSImage exporter?